# Why do some mathematical problems take decades to solve?

Tags: soft-question, math-history, research

I know that FLT took so long because we hadn't had tools to solve the problem at the time it became known.

Upon reading Wikipedia page on Basel problem it appear that same was the reason for it too by the sentence-

> His[Euler's] arguments were based on manipulations that were not justified at the time, although he was later proven correct, and it was not until 1741 that he was able to produce a truly rigorous proof.

So, is it always the case that if a problem take so long to solve, it is only due to the reason that we developed the necessary tools meanwhile?

One can also answer the question by **providing example(s) of mathematical problems which stayed unsolved for decades after formulation despite the fact that all the necessary methods had already existed** at the time. In this way it can be understood that there are other reasons too like our ignorance.

Comment: This is kind of a difficult question. Some problems require machinery to solve and this machinary needs time to be developed. On the other hand it is possible that someone gives an elementary proof of Fermat's last theorem tomorrow. In which case this could have been solved a long time ago as well. In any case you will have difficulties defining what exactly you mean. When do you consider certain techniques or arguments right for their time?

Comment: I am quite certain that there are problems that have gone long unsolved and were finally solved using newer machinery, but has since been proven with old techniques. I can't think of anything right now, but I can't imagine it never having happened.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what OP means, but Apéry's proof (1978) of the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$ uses only results and techniques known for more than 100 years.

Comment: @Mathematician42 I doubt if someone can give an elementary proof of FLT because it is so old and so many good generations of mathematicians have passed to find one.

Comment: As for the Basel problem, Euler gave a heuristic argument that used the Weierstrass factorization theorem (the theorem didn't exist at the time, but he could argue a certain factorization was likely). Since his theoretical prediction of the value seemed to agree with expiremental approximations the result seemed true. In turn people were interested in these factorizations and this led to the factorization theorem. So the techniques were developed later, but the idea was already there.

Comment: That kind of reasoning doesn't work. "I can't find a counterexample so it must be true". Also if you believe your above statement you have answered your question already.

Comment: The irrationality of \pi was first shown in the 18th century. Niven's remarkably short proof in the 20th century would have been perfectly clear even to Newton in the 17th century.

Comment: I think the spirit of the question is good, and the wording can be improved. I don't support the closing/downvoting. @ankit, is this what you are asking: "Provide examples of mathematical problems which stayed unsolved for years after formulation despite the fact that all the necessary methods had already existed at the time?"

Comment: @YuriyS Exactly. Should I rephrase the whole question? Feel free to edit it yourself.

Comment: @ankit, I think you should rephrase the question, yes, at least add a concrete question in bold, so everyone can see what you expect from the answer

Comment: @ankit, since the question can only be answered by examples of problems already solved, open probelms tag doesn't fit here, I'd suggest history related tags

Comment: @YuriyS Should I close/delete this question and post a new one by picking examples from the comment in the question detail?

Comment: @ankit, no, since no answer has been provided yet, you should edit this question (you can rewrite it, as long as no one answered it yet). Of course, it's better not to change the meaning of the question, since someone could be working on their answer right now

Answer (score 2):

The question of whether there is a polynomial-time algorithm for testing primality was around for a few decades before it was settled by the AKS-algorithm, which used no mathematics that wasn't already known at the time the question was formulated. Here's a [reference](https://primes.utm.edu/prove/prove4_3.html).